# Swift TableView with cellForRowAt didn't called from other class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, viewdidload

I am practice how to get tableview work from other class. I have practice with tableview before which work really good and no problem but until now, I want practice how to use tableview in other class - not work. I've tried check few stack overflow questions but doesn't answer my issue. They talk about problem with height, but I have no problem. Everything is fine but only two I notices: cellForRowAt doesn't called, also notice required delegate and datasource inside the ViewDidLoad, I test it and it working but when I move back to other class, doesn't working. I debugged ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear in other class, nothing happen. The numberOfRowsInSection is called, return to 17 in print. What did I missed? Here my full codes below:

I create the struct:

```
struct ReminderDetail {
   struct createTable {
      static var reminderCategoryTable = UITableView()
      static var reminderListTable = UITableView()
    }
}
```

In the ViewController:

```
ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width / 2, height: view.frame.height)
view.addSubview(ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable)
        
ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderListTable.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: 0, width: view.frame.width / 2, height: view.frame.height)
view.addSubview(ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderListTable)
        
GetReminder().startReminderFetching()
```

In my other class:

```
class GetReminder: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   func startReminderFetching() {
      ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
      ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.tableFooterView = .init(frame: .zero)
      fetchingReminderProcessing {
         // This has been called when fetchingReminderProcessing is finish.
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
         ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.delegate = self
         ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.dataSource = self
         ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.register(ReminderCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Category")
         ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.reloadData()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In my tableView - everything else like numberOfRowsInSection is fine but only cellForRowAt doesn't call.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if tableView == ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable {
      print(ReminderDetail.listCategory.count) // It working, it does show 17.
      return ReminderDetail.listCategory.count
   }
return 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
// This doesn't call anything, even print doesn't show anything.
   if tableView == ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable {
      // This doesn't call anything either.
   }
return UITableViewCell()
}
```

I did look online and through stack overflow:

1. Topic talk about height - doesn't solve my issue
2. Topic about ViewDidLoad - it work only inside ViewController but when I want move to GetReminder class and add the ViewDidLoad, nothing happen. Doesn't solve my issue.
3. I tried add two lines to ViewController but got error due to weak warning and does call tableview as I started the app and I don't want that

I tried everything and no luck! Anyone can help me what did I missed??

UPDATE: I tried add auto layout, no luck.

```
view.addSubview(ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable)
ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0 - (view.frame.width / 2)).isActive = true
ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
ReminderDetail.createTable.reminderCategoryTable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: It sounds like UITableView is deciding there's no need to create any cells, which probably means its frame has a width and/or height of zero.  Where is your frame-setting code called from?  If it's in `init` then the view's frame size, and therefore your table's frame size, is likely to be zero.  Try moving that logic to `viewDidLoad` or better yet, use Autolayout.

Comment: I tried add auto layout, tested...nothing happen. Also the tableview frame is in viewDidLoad and nothing happened.

Comment: Do you store a reference to the `GetReminder` instance you create?  If not, it will be released as soon as it's containing scope exits. To be honest the way you have structured your code is pretty icky.  Having unrelated types referring to static properties is basically just globals.

Comment: Have you  tried   `reminderCategoryTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` ?